# How to list all the tickets for a specific machine via SLCLI

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to list down all the tickets associated with a host via slcli. I tried **slcli -ticket -list** but that does not list all the tickets and o/p does not have hostname.

I also tried

> slcli ticket list --closed

but tht fails with below error.

```
#slcli ticket list --closed

SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception that you got, could be due to a lot of data that the request is trying to get

- [How to Solve: Error fetching http headers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers)

Using SLCLI, you can increase the timeout

```
slcli setup
```

**Option (timeout)**

or using a result limit (unfortunately, for this, it's necessary to use *call-api* command)below an example:

```
slcli call-api Account getClosedTickets --limit 50
```

---

### How to list all the tickets for a specific machine via SLCLI

It's necessary use "**call-api**" command for this.

- **For Virtual Guests:**

a) Id:

```
slcli call-api Account getTickets -f tickets.attachedVirtualGuests.id=13552947
```

b) Hostname:

```
slcli call-api Account getTickets -f tickets.attachedVirtualGuests.hostname=testDomain
```

- **For Baremetals/Hardware:**

a) Id:

```
slcli call-api Account getTickets -f tickets.attachedHardware.id=123123
```

b) Hostname:

```
slcli call-api Account getTickets -f tickets.attachedHardware.hostname=testDomain
```

This is the only way through SLCLI, if you would like something more automatic, it's necessary to use an script

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same error. In the meantime you can use the following instead

`slcli --format raw call-api Account getClosedTickets`

You can also use the `--limit` option to limit the number of responses you get back. The issue you are seeing may be due to having a large number of closed tickets on your account.

Comment: Actually, I just tested this again and did not receive any error. May want to test again as it could have been a transient issue with the API.